# Algebraically simple Banach algebras

Tags: banach-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, fa.functional-analysis

There are plenty of semi-simple Banach algebras - this broad class includes C*-algebras and algebras of bounded operators on a given Banach space. On the other hand, it seems unlikely to me that there exists (infinite-dimensional) algebraically simple Banach algebra, that is, a Banach algebra $A$ such that if $J\subseteq A$ is a two-sided ideal, then either $J=\{0\}$ or $J=A$. Is my conjecture true?

EDIT: Of course, the Calkin algebra is the answer. You can delete my question.

Comment: Will the algebra $K(H)$ of compact operators on a Hilbet space satisfy you? It has not non-trivial (closed) two-sided ideals.

Comment: @Sergei: I think, that's exactly the point: is this *algebraically* simple. In other words: Are there non-closed two-sided ideals other than {0} and the whole algebra??

Comment: Yes, the ideal $F(H)$ of all finite-dimensional operators in $K(H)$ is non-trivial. But as far as I understand, if you don't claim that $J$ is closed, then $K(H)$ is not a counterexample for you. I.e. $K(H)$ is not algebraically simple...

Comment: Besides this, do you mean algebras with identity?

Comment: Perhaps the Calkin algebrea $B(H)/K(H)$ is a good candidate.

Comment: Right, Sellapan. There are many Banach algebras that have a largest (necessarily closed) ideal which you can mod out to get an example.

Comment: It may be worth remarking that a notorious open question in Banach algebras asks: does there exist an infinite-dimensional *commutative* Banach algebra (necessarily non-unital and radical) which is algebraically simple? The question has been open since the 1970s (I think).

Answer (score 9):

Observe that, since the group of invertible elements is open, any simple unital Banach algebra is algebraically simple.